# jquery - calling prototype function from outside the object anytime i want

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am not sure how to call my problem, so i hope you guys will help me even if the name of question is not good.

I have a morhpext library downloaded from github. Whole code looks like this:

```
 /*!
 * Morphext - Text Rotating Plugin for jQuery
 * https://github.com/MrSaints/Morphext
 *
 * Built on jQuery Boilerplate
 * http://jqueryboilerplate.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2014 Ian Lai and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://ian.mit-license.org/
 */

/*eslint-env browser */
/*global jQuery:false */
/*eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var pluginName = "Morphext",
        defaults = {
            animation: "bounceIn",
            separator: ",",
            speed: 2000,
            complete: $.noop
        };

    function Plugin (element, options) {
        this.element = $(element);

        this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {
        _init: function () {
            var $that = this;
            this.phrases = [];

            this.element.addClass("morphext");

            $.each(this.element.text().split(this.settings.separator), function (key, value) {
                $that.phrases.push($.trim(value));
            });

            this.index = -1;
            this.animate();
            this.start();
        },
        animate: function () {
            this.index = ++this.index % this.phrases.length;
            this.element[0].innerHTML = "<span class=\"animated " + this.settings.animation + "\">" + this.phrases[this.index] + "</span>";

            if ($.isFunction(this.settings.complete)) {
                this.settings.complete.call(this);
            }
        },
        start: function () {
            var $that = this;
            this._interval = setInterval(function () {
                $that.animate();
            }, this.settings.speed);
        },
        stop: function () {
            this._interval = clearInterval(this._interval);
        },
        kalreg: function () {
            console.log("call invoked!");
        }
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It has its own "functions" - animate, start and stop. Unfortunatelly thay are called only from inside the prototype or in callback function. The last one is called each time the animation is completed (with setInterval/setTimeout). I dont want to wait until animation finishes and then call anything from callback - i want to stop it anytime i want from outside the prototype.
So if i make:

```
    $(".title").Morphext({
        animation: [ "bounceIn"],
        speed: (1000,
        complete: function () {
            if (this.index === this.phrases.length - 1) {
                this.stop();
            };
    }
```

I would also start something that is inside the prototype whenever i want. I created a function "kalreg" (mention first above). I mean something like:

```
$(".title").kalreg()
```

or

```
$(".title").Morphext().kalreg()
```

or

```
$(".title").Morphext(kalreg())
```

In other words: i want to call kalreg function that is a part of Morphext prototype which is called on any DOM element from any moment and any part of the code. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your plugin like the following:

```
(function($){
  var App = function(){};//constructor

    App.prototype.callables = {//Return closure
      hello: function(){
            alert('Hello');
        },
      hi: function(){
          alert('hi');
        }
    }

    $.fn.app = function(){
        return new App().callables;//basically send back an instance of your plugin class with the closure
    }
})(jQuery)

var x = $('#test').app();
x.hello();//call individual functions
x.hi();
```

Comment: My skills are unfortunatelly too small to deal with it (to rewrite someone's other library, which basis on some other library). Any other options are possible?

Comment: Mmm..not that I can think of!! If its opensource effort you could write to the creator!!Normally people help u know!! :) best of luck

Comment: i will try do it on my own, hope to achieve any progress :)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you mentioned looks pretty limited in functionality. You are talking about stopping an animation during execution, and it will require some reauthoring to make that work.

You would be better served by a more robust animation package, it sounds like. I would highly recommend the [Greensock / TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap) library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the project, and it's pretty trivial to call the methods from *'outside'* (I really should be documenting it better though).

Indeed, when `stop()`, and `start()` was originally added, they were added with the intention of allowing you to stop / start it from outside (in addition to the callback).

Unless I've misunderstood your question, what you want to achieve can be done by doing something similar to:

```
var morphext = $("#js-rotating").Morphext({
   animation: "rotateIn"
});
var data = morphext.data("plugin_Morphext");

// Start Morphext (autostarts by default)
data.start();

// Stop Morphext
data.stop();
```

The above is documented in the [release notes](https://github.com/MrSaints/Morphext/releases).

The default functionalites are intentionally limited, but they are easy to [extend](https://github.com/MrSaints/Morphext/issues/10#issuecomment-151848208).

I hope that helps. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to change property anytime is with entering the method from css event, and then access the value like `$self.settings.method_name` or `$self.settings.default_value`.

For example:
on some method or on init:

```
var $self = this;
//method_name
$self.animate();
$self.start();

//default_value
$self.settings.speed = 100;
```

and here i make an example. I change and add method morphext.js so you can see i can change some default value of plugin from inside as always they do. if you want to interact with other dom element instead xml data you can add ajax method and response the incoming change data yes ajax post method will response from remote online check. Here is the address link at infinityfree.net:
https://viena.lovestoblog.com/Morphext/05/index.html

It still with limit effect because i don't know how to install bower on shared hosting. Yeah, Thanks anyway for any respect and attention.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for review. i was read and edit, i'll try to make an example. Maybe tomorrow. It's like math are not simple things to do.